# AS3 changing between animation states

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

I am having troubles coding the animation state changes in flash. I have a little big planet style game with 3 horizontal rows the character can jump between. I have the motion set-up in a tween, but I haven't been able to get the character to transition from running animation to jump back/jump forward animation, and then back to run animation when it has finished transitioning between the layers.

The run animation frames are from 1 - 60, jump back a layer is 61, and jump forward a layer is 62. I haven't begun to worry about stationary yet, so it has no frames.

Edit: I've removed the anmatePlayer function and moved the animation control code into the checkEveryFrame function. I only made a separate function for the animations because I wasn't sure where it should go.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

    public class Main_Test_2 extends MovieClip
    {
        // variables
        private var cam:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        private var player:Player = new Player();
        private var topPosition:uint = 250;
        private var centerPosition:uint = 430;
        private var bottomPosition:uint = 610;
        private var tweenSpeed:Number = 0.33;
        private var UI:UserInterface = new UserInterface();

        public function Main_Test_2():void
        {
            // initialize
            init();
        }
        public function init():void
        {   
            // initialize variables
            stage.addChild (cam);
            player.x = 200;
            player.y = bottomPosition;
            cam.addChild (UI);
            cam.addChild (player);

            // add event listeners
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkEveryFrame);
            UI.topButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, topButtonClick);
            UI.centerButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, centerButtonClick);
            UI.bottomButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bottomButtonClick);
        }

        public function checkEveryFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            cam.x -= player.x - player.x;
            cam.y -= player.y - player.y;
            player.vx = player.x - player.prevX;
            player.vy = player.y - player.prevY;
            player.prevX = player.x;
            player.prevY = player.y;

            /*if (player.y != topPosition || player.y != centerPosition || player.y != topPosition) 
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (61);
            }
            else if (player.y == topPosition || player.y == centerPosition || player.y == topPosition) 
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (1);
            }*/

            if (player.currentFrame == 60)
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (1);
            }
            else if (player.currentFrame < 60)
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (player.currentFrame + 1);
            }

            /*if (player.y < player.prevY) 
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (61);
            }
            else if (player.y > player.prevY)
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (62);
            }
            else if (player.vy == 0) 
            {
                player.gotoAndStop (1);
            }*/
        }

        public function topButtonClick (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("Top Click");
            if (player.y >= bottomPosition)
            {
                var tween01:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, bottomPosition, centerPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
            else if (player.y == centerPosition)
            {
                var tween02:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, centerPosition, topPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
            else if (player.y < topPosition)
            {
                player.y = topPosition;
            }
        }
        public function centerButtonClick (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("Center Click");
            if (player.y > centerPosition)
            {
                var tween01:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, bottomPosition, centerPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
            else if (player.y < centerPosition)
            {
                var tween03:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, topPosition, centerPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
        }
        public function bottomButtonClick (event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("Bottom Click");
            if (player.y <= topPosition)
            {
                var tween03:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, topPosition, centerPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
            else if (player.y == centerPosition)
            {
                var tween4:Tween = new Tween (player, "y", None.easeNone, centerPosition, bottomPosition, tweenSpeed, true);
            }
            else if (player.y > bottomPosition)
            {
                player.y = bottomPosition;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is calling animatePlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. I had to use a timer that executed its action after the timer ran out. I placed it and a line of code to change states in each line of code with the tweens so the animation would go from run to the jump forward/backward animation and back to run at the end of the timer. Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the code that actually calls `animatePlayer`; regardless, below is a solution.

Rather than rely on `MovieClip` to animate, you handle it in your existing `checkEveryFrame`, thereby providing you more exact control to change your animation state exactly when you need to.  I've taken the liberty of unifying your UI clicking actions into a more maintainable function.  Additionally, with the absence of your keybinding function, I've added `playerState` changes to the UI clicking for the sake of demonstration.

As best as I can tell, this should compile, but I'm unable to attempt it without the rest of your objects.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

    public class Main_Test_2 extends MovieClip 
        // variables
        private var cam:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        private var player:Player = new Player();
        private var tweenSpeed:Number = 0.33;
        private var UI:UserInterface = new UserInterface();

        public function Main_Test_2():void {
            // initialize
            init();
        }

        public function init():void {   
            // initialize variables
            stage.addChild(cam);
            player.x = 200;
            player.y = playerTracks[0];
            cam.addChild(UI);
            cam.addChild(player);

            // add event listeners
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkEveryFrame);
            UI.topButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movePlayer);
            UI.centerButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movePlayer);
            UI.bottomButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, movePlayer);
        }

        public function checkEveryFrame(event:Event):void {
            cam.x -= player.x - player.x;
            cam.y -= player.y - player.y;
            player.vx = player.x - player.prevX;
            player.vy = player.y - player.prevY;
            player.prevX = player.x;
            player.prevY = player.y;

            // Animation control
            var a:Array = animations[playerState]; // current animation set
            if (a.length == 2) {
                var maxFrames:int = a[1] - a[0]; // Normalize the max value
                var currentFrame:int = player.currentFrame - a[0]; // Normalize the current value
                var nextFrame:int = normalizedCurrentFrame%maxFrames + a[0] // Modulus of max, and return to actual
                player.gotoAndStop(nextFrame)
            }
        }

        private var playerState:String = "run";
        private var animations:Object = {
            "run":[1,60],
            "jump":[61],
            "jumpForward":[62]
        }

        private var playerTracks:Array = [610, 430, 250];
        private var playerLocIndex:int = 0;

        public function movePlayer(e:MouseEvent):void {
            // Based on the button clicked, increase/decrease/set the index of the destination
            switch (e.currentTarget) {
                case UI.topButton:
                    playerState = "jump";
                    playerLocIndex++;
                    if (playerLocIndex > 2) { playerLocIndex = 2; } // Clamp upper
                    break;
                case UI.centerButton:
                    playerState = "run";
                    playerLocIndex = 1;
                    break;
                case UI.bottomButton:
                    playerState = "jumpForward";
                    playerLocIndex--;
                    if (playerLocIndex < 0) { playerLocIndex = 1; } // Clamp lower
                    break;
            }

            new Tween(player, "y", None.easeNone, player.y, playerTracks[playerLocIndex], tweenSpeed, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the animatePlayer function and event listener. I wasn't sure if I could/should put the animation stuff in the checkEveryFrame function, but they where identical listeners and the code runs fine with the animation code in checkEveryFrame, so this is probably better.

Comment: Did this address the issue then?